# Limit of $\frac{\log x}{x}$ as $x \to 0^+$

Tags: limits

Find $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\log x}{x}$$

The limit of the top is $-\infty$ and the limit of the bottom is $0$ so L'Hôpital's rule cannot be used. How can I go about showing that the limit is $-\infty$?

Comment: This is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: @nik That's exactly what J Cadav is saying. Since it's not indeterminate, l'Hopital's rule is inapplicable.

Comment: @JCadav What else have you tried?

Comment: the limit diverges as $x\rightarrow 0^+$,i hardly believe that there can exist any such limit!

Comment: @AhaanRungta, "not indeterminate" sort of means "obvious", doesn't it?

Comment: @AhaanRungta: And since it's not indeterminate, that means the answer should be known and is easily proven. That's my point. It's like $\frac{1}{\infty}$ or $0 \cdot 0$.

Comment: @abiessu. does the limit even exist when $x\rightarrow 0^-$.I doubt that.

Comment: @abiessu: I seriously doubt that when any expression diverges and it is said to have limit $-\infty$? One thing more, I did not say anything about one-sided or both-sided limit, it was you! What I said and saying is that the limit might not exist as the expression diverges!

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac {\log x} x \leq \log x$$

Comment: Except for $x\in(0,1)$...

Comment: @abiessu, really? Let's try it. $\frac {\log 0.5} {0.5} = -1.38629\dots$ and $\log 0.5 = -0.693147\dots$.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: my apologies, I was thinking of absolute value...

Answer (score 1):

For each $M<0$, find an $x$ so that $\log(x)<M$.  This will imply that $0<x<1$, hence $\frac{1}{x}>1$.  Thus
$$
\frac{1}{x}\log(x)<M.
$$
Take the derivative of $\frac{\log x}{x}$ to get
$$
\frac{1-\log(x)}{x^2}.
$$
For $0<x<1$ this is positive, hence $\frac{\log x}{x}$ is increasing.  Combining the above facts, one learns that for $0<y<x<1$
$$
\frac{\log y}{y}<\frac{\log x}{x}<M.
$$